# Quotes don't work anymore with: git commit -m "My commit message"

Tags: bash, quoting, git, iterm2

I am not sure what is going wrong (terminal, shell, system?), but when I enter:

```
git commit -m "My commit message"
```

this morning, I get:

```
error: pathspec 'My' did not match any file(s) known to git
error: pathspec 'commit' did not match any file(s) known to git
error: pathspec 'message' did not match any file(s) known to git
```

I have just updated `iTerm2` yesterday, that's all I remember changing recently. I'm on MacOS High Sierra 10.13.6 (not a recent update). My version of `git` is 2.19.1, `bash` is `GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin17)` and `iTerm2` is `Build 3.2.5`.

I tried in the Apple provided `Terminal` utility `2.8.2 (404)`, with the same `bash` and `git` and got the same error.

Updated `bash` to `GNU bash, version 4.4.23(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin17.5.0)` and got the same error.

`git` is not alias. `echo "My Commit"` works. `git commit -m "MyCommit"` works.

Trying in `csh`... `git commit -m "My Commit"` works in `csh`!!! So somehow it is a `bash` thing? What `bash` setting could lead to that?

Comment: What Version of git are you running? `git --version`

Comment: My version of git is: 2.19.1.

Comment: Added version details to OP.

Comment: Try the command in another shell, another terminal application. This will hopefully narrow the problem.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski - starting to add details to OP.

Comment: Is `git` an alias? Check with eg `typ git`. Try also the command withe the word `command` first, ie, `command git commit -m etc. `.

Comment: (`typ` in my previous comment should have been `type`)

Answer (score 4):

Found it. I had a function in my `~/.bash_profile` that looked like:

```
git ()
{
  /usr/local/bin/git $*
}
```

which was intending to use a more recent version of `git` than the one provided by MacOS. The handling of the arguments in that function definition is wrong.

Comment: Should be `"$@"` (with the double quotes) instead of unquoted `$*`.  But you could just have done `alias git=/usr/local/bin/git`, or include `/usr/local/bin` early in your `$PATH`.

Comment: I happen to suffer from the same problem, and the enemy was none other than... myself in the past, doing a similar thing thinking that I can be nifty by making my own git command. The consequence was just wasting my future self's 2+ hours.